# Heimdall gives ERROR: Failed to receive handshake response. Result: -7 on samsung J5 (2016)

Tags: samsung, usb-connection-mode, heimdall

I am trying to connect to a `Samsung J5 (2016) SM-J510FN`, using linux ubuntu `20.04` (`libusb-1.0.0`), to flash a TWRP image using heimdall `v1.4.2` (build from master `a2cfdaa`)

I have set the udev based on the git repository [android-udev-rules](https://github.com/M0Rf30/android-udev-rules)

Mobile has USB debbuging on and OEM unlock. And using samsung cables for connection

Mobile phone is visible on lsusb either in normal OS boot or in download mode

```
Normal Boot:
Bus 001 Device 096: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy series, misc. (MTP mode)

Download mode / Odin mode:
Bus 001 Device 097: ID 04e8:685d Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II](Download mode)
```

Running `heimdall print-pit` works without problems. But then:

```
heimdall flash --RECOVERY twrp-3.4.0-0-j5nlte.img  --stdout-errors --verbose --no-reboot

Initialising protocol...
ERROR: Failed to receive handshake response. Result: -7
ERROR: Failed to receive handshake response. Result: -7
ERROR: Protocol initialisation failed!

ERROR: Protocol initialisation failed!

Releasing device interface...
```

My computer only has usb3.0 but also tried with a porthub for usb2.0, this looks like issue [#209](https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall/issues/209)

Any ideas or tips on how to solve this problem ?!

Comment: try [JOdin3](https://odinflashtool.com/downloads/download-jodin3)

Comment: Tried JOdin3 but the same issue

Comment: then you are left with Odin